# me sale un erro al ejecutar el comando php artisan serve

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, composer

Al ejecutar el comando `php.artisan.serve` me sale el siguiente error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Foundation\Application" not found in C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\proyecto\bootstrap\app.php:14""
> Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\proyecto\artisan(20): require_once()
> #1 {main} thrown in C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\proyecto/bootstrap\app.php on line 14`

Comment: Instalaste las dependencias con `composer install`?

Comment: ese comando lo ejecute en la termian de window y me sale esto Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.

Comment: y lo ejecute en visual studio code ysale esto: Composer could not find a composer.json file in C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file. See https://getcomposer.org/basic-usage

Comment: A lo primero: Pero ahi se corta o esta verificando si se puede instalar?. A lo segundo: es porque no se está ejecutando en el directorio de tu proyecto

Comment: entonces me dices que ejecute ese comando en el directorio de mi proyecto?  desde ayer estoy intentando que todo me salga bien pero me quedo estancado en eso

Comment: bueno ya ejecute el comando en mi directorio y este fue el resultado:        
                                                                                                                       
 Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating autoload files
25 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

Comment: Podrias probar con lo que dice en las 2 respuestas mas votadas de [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053231/laravel-error-in-bootstrap-start-php-illuminate-foundation-application-not-fo) de so. Te sugiero ir probando de a una e ir actualizando en la pregunta lo que vas haciendo y el resultado/mensaje. El problema parece ser con las dependencias o el autoload